# A question concerning a short exact sequence with an action

Tags: modules, group-actions, projective-modules

Let $A$ and $D$ be two non-trivial  abelian groups and $B,C$ be two  non-abelian groups.  Also, let $C$ is a free group and  acts on $A,B,D$.

Let $0\to A \xrightarrow{f}B\xrightarrow{g}C\to 0$ be a short exact sequence of groups in which the action of $C$ commutes with  maps $f$ and $g$ ($C$ acts on itself trivially). Also, let there exist homomorphisms  $h_1 :D\to B$ and $h_2 :B\to D$ (commuting with the action of $C$) so that $h_2 \circ  h_1 =1_D$.

If $A$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}C$-module, then is $D$ a projective $\mathbb{Z}C$-module?

Comment: Try taking $A=0$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Is $0$ a free $\mathbb{Z}C$-module?

Comment: Yes, it's the free $\mathbb{Z}C$-module on zero generators. Or if that disturbs you, then start with an example where $A=0$ and then replace $A$ and $B$ with $A\times\mathbb{Z}C$ and $B\times\mathbb{Z}C$ respectively.

Comment: @JeremyRickard I think when $A=0$, we have $B\cong C$ from the short exact sequence. On the other hand, $D$ is a semidirct factor of $B$. So $D=0$ or $D\cong C$. Is it correct?

Comment: @JeremyRickard Obviously when $B$ and $C$ are abelian, the claim holds.

Comment: No, the claim doesn’t hold even if $B$ and $C$ are abelian. Take $A=0$ and $B=C=D$ cyclic of order two, all with trivial $C$-action. Then $D=C$ is not a projective $\mathbb{Z}C$-module.

Comment: @JeremyRickard That's true, but in this question, I take $A$ is non-trivial.

Comment: @JeremyRickard If I add this condition that $C$ is a free group, then can I tell the answer is positive?

Comment: From group theoretical point of view, since $C$ is a free group, then $B=A\rtimes C$.

Comment: Even if $C$ is a free group, $D$ could be $\mathbb{Z}$ with trivial $C$-action, which is not a projective $\mathbb{Z}C$-module.